# how to use all child component of one module into main component of a module via component selector in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, export

I have one module in ionic and some inner sub-parts component in that same module.

structure of the module is look like :

```
Car Folder

     Straring Folder
     |-> stearing.component.ts
     |-> stearing.component.html

     Tire Folder
     |-> tire.component.ts
     |-> tire.component.html

|-> Car.component.ts
|-> Car.component.html
|-> Car.module.ts
```

In this structure, car is a module which contain one main component called `car`. and two sub component called `stearing` and `tire`

**Car's html** :

```
<div class="container">
  <stearing></stearing>
  <tire></tire>
</div>
```

**Car.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StearingComponent } from './stearing.component';
import { TireComponent } from './tire.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [stearingComponent, tireComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class CarModule { }
```

After this configuration, when I run project with ionic CLI, project is running successful, but that two componet `tire` and `stearing` 's html and UI not load into screen..

This above code will not work because we not export that two component yet.. so selector will not render the UI of that component onto the screen.

For result, we needs to export that components (tire, stearing) and then we can use it as a selector. For export each component. we need to convert it into `single component module`. So after new structure with exported components are look like this :

```
Car Folder

     Straring Folder
     |-> stearing.component.ts
     |-> stearing.component.html
     |-> stearing.module.ts

     Tire Folder
     |-> tire.component.ts
     |-> tire.component.html
     |-> tire.module.ts

|-> Car.component.ts
|-> Car.component.html
|-> Car.module.ts
```

And `tire` and `stearing` module will export only that component..Then we needs to import that both module into main `car` module and then selector will work.

But My actual problem is that, I don't want to export each component by converting it into `single component module`...
without export child component, is there any way to access it's selector ?

If anyone know solution, then please report here. It will saves my day..

What I Have tried :

I have create all component into one module and export all component from one module file named : index.module.ts and then import that module file into main module... and I can access it's all component, but It seems invalid and weird..